# Time format in excel imported to asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, excel, vb.net-2010

i'm importing an excel file to asp.net and i'm filling it into a grid view...

i have a column for time in the excel sheet i'm inserting the following format "hh:mm" but i keep getting the full format in the asp.net

example: 11:11 in excel i get in asp.net 12/30/1899 11:11:00 AM
although the format of the cell in excel is h:mm

i'm trying to change the value in the datatable but it's not working...
how can i solve this?

```
 timee = row("TIME_TO_SEND")
 finalTime = timee.Substring(0, 5)
 row("TIME_TO_SEND")="hh:mm"
```

note that the convert of the date is working... but my problem is that in the datatable the format of the date is complete... so when i'm filling the grid view with the datatable i'm getting in the time column:12/30/1899 11:11:00 AM

Comment: use formatting on grid level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use

```
DateTime.Parse(row("TIME_TO_SEND"), "hh:mm")
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Comment: the convert of the date is working... but my problem is that in the datatable the format of the date is complete... so when i'm filling the grid view with the datatable i'm getting in the time column:12/30/1899 11:11:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

When you set the format in excel,excel keep the all data but show it using the format. In your case also the column contains the whole datetime but show you only the portion you set.
To get the required result do something like this.

```
DateTime timee = DateTime.Parse(row("TIME_TO_SEND"));
string finalTime = timee.ToString("hh:mm");
```

**Update:-**
Since you want to format the datetime in gridview at runtime use GridView'sRowDataBound event which is fired everytime a row is bound .

suppose your time column is 3rd column then with 0 index it will be 2nd here how you can format it.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
          DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(e.Row.Cells[2].Text);
          e.Row.Cells[2].Text = dt.ToString("hh:mm");
     }
}
```

Comment: the convert of the date is working... but my problem is that in the datatable the format of the date is complete... so when i'm filling the grid view with the datatable i'm getting in the time column:12/30/1899 11:11:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

What you are getting is a `DateTime`.

Use the [`DateTime.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) to format it correctly.

```
finalTime = row("TIME_TO_SEND").ToString("hh:mm")
```

Comment: the convert of the date is working... but my problem is that in the datatable the format of the date is complete... so when i'm filling the grid view with the datatable i'm getting in the time column:12/30/1899 11:11:00 AM